# Confirm Form Submission rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a view that displays list of users for a event and I have provided CRUD actions views for users view.
When superadmin tries to edit details of user, everything works fine.
but when user tries to use back button to return to its existing state, a Confirm Form Submission message displays.
And there's no error in rails console.

is there a way to solve this issue?
[Confirm Form Submission Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a53I3.png)

Comment: Are you redirecting in your controller after a successful submission? You really should post some code.

Comment: @Ash actually the issue is not while redirecting. it is when user is on edit view and presses back button of browser to return to list.

Comment: How are you getting to the edit page? Via a POST request?

Comment: Yes and on back button it redirects to list page.